# Are we currently, with todays technology, able to stick molecules together?

Tags: material-science, nanoscience

I was wondering if we, with todays technology, are able to bind molecules together in the lab in specific ways. Meaning, are we able to, lets say, stick iron molecules together to form a microscopic piece of pure iron?

I started thinking about this while looking at carbon nanotubes which are formed in their specific tube structure and if we could do this with other materials we could create some insanely perfect things.

When looking on google i get a whole lot of star trek fiction about the replicator. But in fact molecular manufacturing seems to be a real study and i'm wondering if we are able to do the basic thing in a lab.

Comment: Are you looking for intramolecular forces? http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3996/  might get you a step into the direction you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for the forces between molecules. I just wish to know if we are able to create stuff from basic molecules in the lab or not. I was watching a documentary on katanas where they went into the molecular structure of the sword and how it improved the sword. Then I saw a paper about carbon nanotubes and started wondering if, since we are able to create these carbon structures, we are also able to create other stuff in the lab and given enough funding might even create something bigger like the perfect katana (no pollutants).

Comment: Iron is crystalline in isolation. It doesn't have molecules per se unless combined with something else. you might be interested in Rolls Royce production of turbine blades for their engine by growing single crystals. 
https://www.theengineer.co.uk/issues/june-2015-online/jewel-in-the-crown-rolls-royces-single-crystal-turbine-blade-casting-foundry/

Comment: Very interesting, but its still casting as i understand it. I'd like to go beyond casting. And get  more into molecular manufacturing/nano manufacturing. The cast made by Rolls Royce is still only a cast containing contaminants as no metal is pure. While if you assemble something atom by atom or molecule by molecule you know exactly how pure and strong it is. While i don't like using SciFi when asking about actual science to make things clear look at http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Molecular_construction_device . This is somewhat what i'm asking, except realistically.

Comment: This is, or rather will be when it happens, an Engineering SE topic. For moment, here is a short list and it seems there is a clear divide between biological based techniques and scaled down "factory" techniques. http://io9.gizmodo.com/5967198/8-incredible-nanotechnologies-that-actually-exist-in-the-real-world It's a popsci magazine article rather than any formal review, but it does seem we are still a low way away from building from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My question is not from an engineering standpoint though. It was purely from a physics perspective, if we are able to do stuff like this, at a basic level, yet. And according to your article we are somewhat doing it. Although not with metals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know of is direct manipulation of atoms and molecules on a surface using STM setups (scanning tunneling microscopes).

Maybe you have seen this famous image before:
[image]

Here is a youtube video showing off what they can do:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSCX78-8-q0

Here is an article, which gives some nice overview and also some nice visuals:
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506038
As a highlight, researchers have been able to perform a process for a molecular reaction "where all the basic reactions steps; dissociation, diffusion and association, have been realized by using several manipulation techniques in a step-by-step manner."

Comment: Haha, that movie. Very interesting though. Seems like the basics are there.